# Getting Error while running program on linux. On windows it is working fine

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I made a java program. I used eclipse and it's a maven project. Now when i run the program from windows command prompt, then it's run fine. Here How i am running it from windows command prompt

```
D:\Personal Work\eclipse 32 Bit\workspace\....\target\classes>
java -cp ".;..\dependency-jars\*"  com/softech/ls360/integration/BatchImport vintners
```

It is working fine. My dependency jar folder contains these jar files

[image: dependency-jars]

Now when i run the same program from linux. Here how i am runnign it

```
root@Basit:/home/test/script/classes# java -cp .;../dependency-jars/*;  com.s
oftech.ls360.integration.BatchImport vintners
```

Then i am getting the errors that

```
....
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
../dependency-jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar: line 1: PK??: command not found
../dependency-jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar: line 2:
../dependency-jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar: line 2: ?8: command not found
../dependency-jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar: line 3: syntax error near unex
pected token `)'
../dependency-jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar: line 3: ?     ¶META-INF/MANIFE
ST.MF?VKo
     _¦?z?  ?%+v?N??!ö!P@
                         (
                          _?o.5?$
com.softech.ls360.integration.BatchImport: command not found
```

Why i am getting these errors. How can i run it on linux? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `:` instead of `;` in classpath on linux envrionment. Assuming you have jars placed properly, then simply changing this:

```
java -cp .;../dependency-jars/*;  com.s
oftech.ls360.integration.BatchImport vintners
```

to

```
java -cp .:../dependency-jars/*:  com.s
oftech.ls360.integration.BatchImport vintners
```

should work

Learn more about setting classpath here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon is making Bash invoke the java command with no classpath, then tries to execute each jar directly, seeking a shebang where none exists. This leads to JAR headers being printed as part of the error.

Use `:` to separate jars instead of semicolons on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes:

1. First, the classpath separator is ':' rather than ';' on Linux
2. Second, you'll need to escape the wildcard character with a backslash ('\'), or the shell will expand it and mess things up. You want Java to see the '*' character and expand it itself. The Windows shell doesn't expand wildcards on command lines, so this isn't a problem there.

So, all together, you'll want to use something like

```
java -cp .:../dependency-jars/\*:  com.softech.ls360.integration.BatchImport vintners
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use : instead of ; as a sperator of the class path files.